# Maxscript renders saving blank/empty file

Tags: render, 3dsmax, maxscript

I am having trouble saving renders to an output file (using Maxscript). I use the following code in my script:

---

```
`render camera:$VRayCam002 frame:1 outputfile:"testscript.tif"`
```

---

When I run the code, I can see the scene render in the frame buffer, but the saved file, 'testscript.tif' is blank, i.e. the image is all black.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: In what folder are you expecting the file to be?

Comment: I didn't specify a folder, but by default, it saves the file to the sceneassets folder, so on completing the render, it prints a statement like--`BitMap:_MyDocumentsPath_\3dsMax\sceneassets\images\testscript.tif`

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem. Apparently, while doing things pertaining to the render scene dialog settings in MAXScript, the actual dialog should be closed. See [here](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/MAXScript-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-30AF1E53-5A69-402D-84D6-4D6ECCDD6D20.htm,topicNumber=d30e673898) from MAXScript help documentation.

With the dialog closed, the image saves properly

Also be sure to set
`rendSaveFile =true` and `rendOutputFilename =  "whatevername"`